# Deploying to Vercel - Can we deploy React Apps served in Node Servers?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, vercel

**My Situation**

I'm able to deploy APIs to production in Vercel with a vercel.json:

```
{
"builds": [{ "src": "backend-build/index.js", "use": "@now/node-server" }],
"routes": [
    {
        "src": "(.*)",
        "methods": ["GET", "POST", "PATCH", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"],
        "headers": {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true"
        },

        "dest": "backend-build/index.js",
        "continue": true
    }
]
```

}

Here's an example of my API I made:
https://kijiji-backend.vercel.app/api/test

**The Problem**

But! when trying to serve up my React's build folder (created with React's `npm run build`) in Node.js:

```
app.use("/api/test", (req, res) => {
    res.send("hi");
});

//Render React App
//All other roues will be handled by
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "build")));
app.get("*", function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "build", "index.html"));
});
```

The website won't actually render any React (blank page). As seen here:
https://kijiji-backend.vercel.app

You could see in the browser console, there's an error of:

`2.b2517795.chunk.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'`

This all works in locally in my computer, however, when deployed to Vercel, React won't render.

**Vercel log:**
[image]

Comment: Check the following: https://vercel.com/guides/using-express-with-vercel

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `basename="/"` to your `<BrowserRouter>` tag in your `src/index.js`. 
 If you are using `react-router-dom`.